# child Reference in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Click here to see the Database]

I want to retrieve Activities id1 and id2 only so I can save it in a list. However, I do this and the last line returns the whole object reference

```
{Category 1={name=joy, Sprint={Activities={id2=23r90u9329r,
id1=jf92jf943jf94j3f9}, startingDate =08092017, sprintOverallScore=1,
Ending Date=08092017, Number of Weeks=2}}
```

How can I get just `Activities={id2=23r90u9329r,
    id1=jf92jf943jf94j3f9}`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);


        //getting the reference of artists node
        databaseCategories = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Categories");


databaseCategories.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                //clear the list
                currentCategories.clear();

                //iterate through all the node
                for(DataSnapshot postsnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                    //Category j = postsnapshot.getValue(Category.class);

                    System.out.println("test: " + postsnapshot.getValue());
```

I tried creating 2 database references like this but it's returning NULL:

```
DatabaseReference databaseCategories, databaseCategories2;

             ....


databaseCategories.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                //clear the list
                currentCategories.clear();

                //iterate through all the node
                for(DataSnapshot postsnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    String g = postsnapshot.getKey(); //get the id

                    databaseCategories2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CategoryNew").child(g+"").child("Category 1").child("Sprint").child("Activities");


                    databaseCategories2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            System.out.println("test new: " + dataSnapshot.getValue()); //returning NULL

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're attaching a listener on `/Categories` your `onDataChange` will get called with a `dataSnapshot` with the complete value under that. You loop over its children, which brings you one level down, but your `postSnapshot` then still is the entire data under `hsdhs...`. You'll need to navigate the rest of the snapshot in your code too, to get to the activities:

```
databaseCategories = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Categories");

databaseCategories.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //iterate through the categories
        for(DataSnapshot categorySnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            DataSnapshot activitiesSnapshot = categorySnapshot.child("Category1/Sprint/Activities");
            for(DataSnapshot activitySnapshot: activitiesSnapshot.getChildren()){
                System.out.println(activitySnapshot.getKey()+": "+activitySnapshot.getValue(String.class));
            }
        }
    }

    ...
```

Note that this is quite wasteful, both in the amount of code you have to write and in the amount of data that is retrieved. If you have a common use-case in your app to find the activities for a category, consider storing those as a top-level list:

```
CategoryActivities
  CategoryId
    ActivityId1: "value 1"
    ActivityId2: "value 2"
```

With this structure you can more easily read precisely the data you need, saving both data transfer and the deeply nested code.

Comment: thanks for the tip I will probably going to end up doing that because it is true about the nested loop. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes I did already but since I have a low reputation number, it doesn't let me record the feedback, but I was satisfied with your answer, thanks.